# Spring webflux security with mock user for the backend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

My spring webflux security code is,

```
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http.securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);
        return http.authorizeExchange().matchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(props.getSecurity().getIgnorePatterns()).permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(exception))
                .accessDeniedHandler((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(exception))
                .and().build();
    }
```

Now, I have the below code to get the logged in user details.

```
public Mono<AppUserDetails> getUser() {
    Mono<Principal> principalMono = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication).cast(Principal.class);
    
            principalMono.flatMap(principal -> {
                if (principal instanceof AuthenticatedUserToken) {
                    final AppUserDetails user = ((AuthenticatedUserToken<?>) principal).getUser();
                    return Mono.just(user);
                } 
    
                return Mono.error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid access"));
            }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                return Mono.empty();
            }));
}
```

I have an API to create a project and the project table has audit column as well like createdBy user. I am using the above code( getUser() method ) to retrieve the logged in user and get userId from there.

Now, trying to test this API thru postman with just a mock user with userId 1 instead of logging  in with the real user as the front end is not ready yet.

How can I run the spring boot app with mock user and return mock user id when the getUser() method is invoked so that I can test end to end.

Comment: what have you tried? post what you have tried and your faulty code, you mock a function like you would mock any other function in spring boot. If you have no idea, i suggest you google the spring boot official documentation and read the chapter on testing spring boot applications, then try to write a test and if you run into a specific error you post it here with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this with the code below.

Created a conditional based class for Mock user.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "admin.service", value = "security.mode", havingValue = "MOCK")
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class MockSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties appProps;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        return http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/**").permitAll().and().csrf().disable().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticatedPrinciplaProvider mockSecurityPrincipalProvider() {
        return new MockSecurityContextPrincipleProvider(props.getSecurity().getMock());
    }

}
```